# How long does cooked pasta last in the fridge?

Tags: pasta, storage-lifetime, refrigerator

I sometimes cook more pasta than I intend to eat or use at once and store the rest in a container in the fridge (just plain, cooked pasta). How long would it store safely for?

Comment: What kind of pasta? The sugars in each kind may differ

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking about the shape or what it's made of? They are "mini shells" made from "100% hard amber durum semolina" in this case. I'm not sure if that answers your question :)

Comment: 100%, eh? I suspect your container lies to you.

Comment: @Adam manufacturers mean that 100% of the *wheat* is such-and-such.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17887 is as good advice as any I'd give.

In my experience, it gets some slimy mold stuff on it. If it feels slimy, its probably not good to eat, although the mold might taste delicious, you never know...

Comment: I LOVE that site. I highly recommend stilltasty.com for anyone looking to know how long to keep a food item and how to store it.

Comment: Some molds are antibiotics, too! :-p

Comment: Critical information in the link should be posted in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I don't keep plain cooked pasta or rice in the fridge for longer than 2 days. Both of these are starchy and pH neutral which makes a perfect environment for for mold / bacteria to grow.

Answer (score 0):

I've refrigerated pasta for 7 days or so before. I wouldn't keep it any longer. If it starts to grow fuzzies or smell off, don't eat it.

Comment: In this particular case, it doesn't seem to smell but there was lots of condensation in the container and the pasta looks a bit "glossy", if that matters.

Comment: I wouldn't eat it then. If something looks like it might be bad, it's generally safer to leave it alone. I like to imagine that it's an instinctual response that causes us to question bad food. I trust it :)

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I was just being lazy because in the time I spent writing this question I could have already cooked fresh pasta :) (though on the other hand, I'd rather not waste food that is edible, right?)

Answer (score -2):

Store the pasta in the fridge in water. Water should just cover the pasta. It will keep for a good while. Better yet, when you drain and heat it in the microwave, it will taste good as new.

Comment: Doesn't this make it mushy? How does it preserve anything?

Answer (score -7):

I've stored it for over 2 weeks without water and all that crap others are telling you. As long as it doesn't have green mold on it, it is safe to eat. Otherwise only a really bad smell would be bad. Easily over 14 days if kept in a container with a lid. In fact I store my pasta sause in a container as well for just as long. People will have you throwing away good food just because they don't know or are uninformed. I've save a bunch of money doing it my way. Like meats for over 2 weeks and fruits and vegatables. If it ain't got green on it or smells bad then it's still good to eat.

Comment: "If it ain't got green on it or smells bad then it's still good to eat." This is terrible advice, which can kill people. Food contaminated with botulism, for example, doesn't look mouldy and doesn't necessarily smell off.

Answer (score -7):

If you're concerned after several days of storage, re-boil it for a minute or two. This will take it back to it's original cooking date.

Comment: This isn't accurate advice, and following it is potentially unsafe.