# Will my pasta taste fine 5 days later?

Tags: food-safety, pasta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does cooked pasta last in the fridge?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2030/how-long-does-cooked-pasta-last-in-the-fridge)

I work Monday to Friday, and dont pack very good lunches, I recently bought a bunch of pasta and sauce, my plan is to make 5 days worth of pasta for lunches on Sunday night and keep it all in the fridge and bring one portion for lunch each day, will my pasta still taste fine for my Thursday and Friday lunch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep pasta in the fridge for up to 5 days, but it may well be beginning to go off at day 5. If it smells musty discard it. Another option would be to freeze it; you can drop it into boiling water straight from the freezer from what I've read.
I also found this earlier question here [How long does cooked pasta last in the fridge?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2030/how-long-does-cooked-pasta-last-in-the-fridge) which is pretty much what you're asking